# Excluding a dependency from other modules that use my library

Tags: maven, slf4j

I'm writing a library that uses SLF4J for logging. The library contains classes with a Main() method, so I want to include in the classpath some implementation for SLF4J, such as Logback.

But I don't want to "contaminate" other libraries that will add my library as a dependency (meaning, I don't want them to transitively get Logback as a dependency). So I want to tell Maven: "Add Logback as a dependency but don't add it as a transitive dependency in other models using this library".

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suppose you're looking for [optional dependencies](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-optional-and-excludes-dependencies.html)